# How to use a “preview API” and/or an “incubating API” in project via Maven or Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, configuration

As part of the current Java enhancement development process adopted by the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project, some new features under development for Java are offered in pre-release form as a [preview API](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12) or as an [incubating API](https://openjdk.org/jeps/11).

For example:

- [JEP 425: Virtual Threads (Preview)](https://openjdk.org/jeps/425)
- [JEP 428: Structured Concurrency (Incubator)](https://openjdk.org/jeps/428)

If one wishes to try these new pre-release features using [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) for a project driven by [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) or [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle), what configuration to the project and/or [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) is needed?

Comment: Is this is a Maven/gradle project - se the corresponding compiler options in Maven/Gradle build files. Otherwise there is Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler | Javac Options | **Additional command line parameters** you can pass.

Comment: For Gradle, see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74311121/642706) on a duplicate Question.

Answer (score 1):

In maven for example, if you put

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The IDE will automatically detect the flag and will enable preview support. Incubator features need to be imported as modules.

I would suggest to use Maven, because Gradle always lags with introducing support for new Java versions.