# Java 19 preview, incubator features with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, java-19, project-loom

Java 19 has new features: virtual threads (as preview) and structured concurrency (as incubator). Gradle 7.6 will support Java 19. Given that 7.6-rc-1 is available, how can I try out these new features? I have working Bash scripts like the following:

compile:

```bash
javac --release 19 --enable-preview \
--add-modules jdk.incubator.concurrent \
-cp $CLASSPATH \
[snip]
```

run:

```bash
java --enable-preview \
-cp $CLASSPATH \
--add-modules jdk.incubator.concurrent \
net.codetojoy.Runner
```

How are these flags translated into Gradle?

Answer (score 3):

Consider this `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "net.codetojoy.Runner"

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs.addAll(['--release', '19']) 
    options.compilerArgs.addAll(['--enable-preview'])
    options.compilerArgs.addAll(['--add-modules', 'jdk.incubator.concurrent'])
}

application {
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['--enable-preview', 
                                 '--add-modules', 'jdk.incubator.concurrent']
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/main/egg_JDK19_Preview) is a working example, which uses the Gradle wrapper for 7.6-rc-1, and illustrates structured concurrency.

Comment: The link to the working example leads to a missing GitHub page.

Comment: Link is fixed now: apologies for inconvenience.